# Getting a NaN when calculating

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a `NaN` value here when I try to input some number on my *html*. I don't know why.

```
var firstNumber= document.getElementById("numberone").value;
var secondNumber = document.getElementById("numbertwo").value;

function addition(){
  var result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  document.getElementById("equals").innerHTML = result;
}

function subtraction(){
  var result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
  document.getElementById("equals").innerHTML = result;
}

function multiplication(){
  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  document.getElementById("equals").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: `.value` are strings ...

Comment: the input are numbers though. So how would I not get a NaN with my inputs?

Comment: You need to convert your inputs using parseInt or similar function.

Comment: `.value` ALWAYS returns strings

Comment: `.value` are strings regardless of content - `parseFloat`/`parseInt`/`Number` ... are just 3 methods you can use to solve your problem

Comment: i used parseFloat and nothing is being output now

Comment: well ... the code you posted wont output anything

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the value from the input using `parseInt(value, base)`, where value is the input value and base the base in mathematical numeral systems.

```
var firstNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberone").value, 10);
var secondNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("numbertwo").value, 10);
```

You can read more about here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Edit:
I assumed that you are handling integer values, but you can try [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to handle float values or, also, use a library to manipulate and format numbers like [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)

Comment: this assumes the OP only wants to work with integers, of course

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` get set once at the begining of the program (they more likely to be just empty strings, the two inputs are not yet filled whith anything by the time those two lines of code that set them are executed). You should get the values whenever one of the functions that relly on those values is executed:

```
function getValue(id) {
    return +document.getElementById(id).value; // get the value of the input whose ID is id and convert the value to a number using unary +
} 

function addition(){
  var result = getValue("numberone") + getValue("numbertwo"); // use getValue here
  document.getElementById("equals").innerHTML = result;
}

function subtraction(){
  var result = getValue("numberone") - getValue("numbertwo"); // here two
  document.getElementById("equals").innerHTML = result;
}

//...
```